# Margin and padding are doubled using float and inline-block

Tags: html, css

It seems as though when I use float or inline-block on elements, their margin or padding gets doubled. To illustrate this, the margin between the middle and bottom sections is 5%. However, the size of the top section is also 5%, and the top section is half as large as the bottom section.

When I was checking the JSFiddle and re-sizing the window I noticed that the top section does not scale in terms of height relative to the width of the window of the screen, but the vertical margin does.

Any fix or explanation would be appreciated.

```css
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
}
div {
  outline: black solid 1px;
}
.top {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5%;
}
.section {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 5% 0px;
}
.left1 {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
}
.left2 {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 5% 0px;
}
.right1 {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 66.66666%;
}
.right2 {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33.33333%;
}
.right21 {
  width: 80%;
}
.right22 {
  width: 80%;
}
.bottom {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="section">top section 1
  </div>
  <div class="section">top section 2
  </div>
  <div class="section">top section 3
  </div>
  <div class="section">top section 4
  </div>
  <div class="section">top section 5</div>

</div>
<div class="left">
  <div class="left1">left 1
  </div>
  <div class="left2">left 2</div>

</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="right1">right 1
  </div>
  <div class="right2">
    <div class="right21">right 2 1
    </div>
    <div class="right22">right 2 2</div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="bottom">
  bottom
</div>
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9c8uoz0q/

Comment: I suppose that seems unnecessary to me? I don't think I understand what that accomplishes. Let ask my question in another manner. If I were to change the margin of the middle section to 5vh instead of 5%, it acts properly. Why is this? Isn't 5vh the same as 5% in this case?

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `.top` is in fixed position and your `.bottom` is floating.

Clear the float for your `.bottom` and remove the fixed position for you `.top` and you should see that it scale like you meant to.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c8uoz0q/1/)

Comment: Both the margin above and below the middle section are still 10% instead of the 5% that is listed in the CSS.

Comment: how is it 10%? your .top height is not 5% since the parent height is determine by their child height which is 100%.

Comment: The .top height is clearly not 100%. It is 5%, and the children of .top (.section) take up 100% of that 5% height. I'm not talking about the height of the top section anyways. I mean that the margin between .left or .right and the top of the screen should be 5% of the screen, and it is taking up 10% of the screen. If it was 5% of the screen, there would be no gap between .top or .left and .right.

Comment: OK, so you are referring to your fiddle instead of mine.  Your height is 5% of the total viewport height (doesn't scale against viewport width) while your content margin is scaling against viewport width (width * percentage).

Comment: I guess I should clarify. The .top needs to be fixed and have a height that is 5%. But anyways, why would something like margin-top scale with width?